# NameError: global name 'key_str' is not defined

Tags: python-2.5

in below script i am getting the error

```
if not any(d['KEY'] == key_str for d in records):
NameError: global name 'key_str' is not defined
```

I am transposing a input file set of columns to rows and rows to columns.
please help:

```
if "Sales-Target" in fdmContext["LOCNAME"]:
        filename = fdmContext["FILENAME"]
        dim_cols = 7
        period_dim_index = 0
        input_filename = (os.path.abspath("E:/FDMEE/")+"\%s" % filename)
        months = ['M%s' % x for x in range(1,13)]
        first_row = True
        headers = []
        records = []
        output_filename = "%s_out.%s" % (input_filename.split(".")[0],input_filename.split(".")[1])
        input_f = open(input_filename)
        for line in input_f:
            if first_row:
                headers = line.split(",")
                headers = [x.rstrip() for x in headers]
            else:
                data = line.split(",")
                for i in range(dim_cols,len(headers)):
                    key = data[:dim_cols]
                    del key[period_dim_index]
                    key.append(headers[i])
                    key_str = "_".join(key)
                    if not any(d['KEY'] == key_str for d in records):
                        record = {}
                        record["ACCOUNT"] = headers[i]
                        record["KEY"] = key_str
                        record["PERIODS"] = {}
                        for j in range(0,dim_cols):
                            if j == period_dim_index:
                                record["PERIODS"][data[j]] = data[i].rstrip()
                            else:
                                record[headers[j]] = data[j]
                        records.append(record)
                    else:
                        record = (d for d in records if d["KEY"] == key_str).next()
                        record["PERIODS"][data[period_dim_index]] = data[i].rstrip()
            first_row = False
        input_f.close()
        output_f = open(output_filename,"w")
        row=[]
        [row.append(x) for x in headers[:dim_cols] if headers.index(x) != period_dim_index]
        row.append("ACCOUNT")
        [row.append(x) for x in months]
        output_f.write("%s\n" % ",".join(row))
        for record in records:
            row = [record[x] for x in headers[:dim_cols] if headers.index(x) != period_dim_index]
            row.append(record["ACCOUNT"])
            for month in months:
                if month in record["PERIODS"].keys():
                    row.append(record["PERIODS"][month])
                else:
                    row.append("0")
            output_f.write("%s\n" % ",".join(row))
        output_f.close()
```

Comment: 2.*5*? That's a strange version to be on.

Comment: Are you sure your indentation is correct?

Comment: Is this inside a class statement for some reason?

Comment: @bernie : Yes my Indentation is correct.